# Next.js (Vercel) + SendGrid not working on production but working locally

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sendgrid, vercel

I have a **Next.js** website that's hosted in **Vercel**. Inside the website I have a simple contact form that just takes user input and saves it to MongoDB.
Additional to this, I wanted to make sure the admin of the website knows when a new form submission was added so I decided to use **SendGrid** to send the email for me.

I configured everything, wrote the code, tested locally, emails were sent but when I deployed to production I noticed the email was not being sent.

I've then went to Vercel and saw that I forgot to add the Environmental Variable for SendGrid. I've added that, re-deployed and tested out if the variable is being taken into consideration on production.

Here is a SS of the logs from production

[image]

as a result of the following code that's inside my `api/form.js`

```
if (process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY) {
  console.log("It is set!");
} else {
  console.log("No set!");
}
```

So ENV variable is set and ready to rock but email still doesn't come trough.

I read a lot about the issue and I'm not the only one having this problem. The most common mistake was not awaiting for the `mail.send(dataToSend)` inside the async function. I fixed this but still have no clue why the email is not being sent in production.

the handle function inside `form.js`

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const data = req.body;

    const message = `
      Nume: <b>${data["Nume"]}</b>\r\n
      Prenume: <b>${data["Prenume"]}</b>\r\n
      Cât de mulțumit/ă sunteți de atitudinea personalului nostru?: <b>${data["Cât de mulțumit/ă sunteți de atitudinea personalului nostru?"]}</b>\r\n
      Cât de mulțumit/ă sunteți de modul de recoltare?: <b>${data["Cât de mulțumit/ă sunteți de modul de recoltare?"]}</b>\r\n
      Cât de mulțumit/ă sunteți promptitudinea rezultatelor?: <b>${data["Cât de mulțumit/ă sunteți promptitudinea rezultatelor?"]}</b>\r\n
      Cât de mulțumit/ă sunteți de forma si modul de prezentare a buletinului de rezultate?: <b>${data["Cât de mulțumit/ă sunteți de forma si modul de prezentare a buletinului de rezultate?"]}</b>\r\n
      Aveți vreo sugestie referitoare la îmbunătățirea activității noastre?: <b>${data["Aveți vreo sugestie referitoare la îmbunătățirea activității noastre?"]}</b>
    `;

    const dataPayload = {
      to: ["laboratorberceanu@gmail.com", "nandra.mihnea@gmail.com"],
      from: "chestionar@laboratorberceanu.ro",
      subject: 'Răspuns NOU pentru chestionarul de satisfacție',
      text: message,
      html: message.replace(/\r\n/g, '<br>')
    }

    const client = await clientPromise;
    const db = client.db("laborator-berceanu");

    const chestionar = await db.collection("chestionar");
    await chestionar.insertOne(data);
    res.status(201).json({ message: "Data inserted successfully!" });

    await mail.send(dataPayload);
  }
};
```

the `postData` function inside my React component

```
 const postData = async (formData) => {
    const response = await fetch("/api/form", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });

    return response.json();
  };
```

**Any advice would be helpful and much appreciated.**